# Learning Python the Hard Way: Ex16 'w+'

Tags: python

I had a question regarding the extra credit in this exercise. I wanted this script to not only open and write to the file but read what I just wrote into the file back to me. At the print target.read() portion the console prints bunch of empty space but not the writing I had input. The writing part to the file worked because when I open the actual .txt file the text is there. Where are all the extra empty spaces coming from? And why won't it read me the text back? Thank you!

```
print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" %(line1, line2, line3))

print target.read()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the file cursor back to the start of the file before using `read()`.

```
In [14]: target=open("data.txt","w+")

In [15]: target.write("foo bar")

In [21]: target.tell()    #current position of  the cursor
Out[21]: 7L

In [16]: target.seek(0)   #change it to 0

In [17]: target.read()
Out[17]: 'foo bar'
```

help on `seek()`:

```
In [18]: print target.seek.__doc__
seek(offset[, whence]) -> None.  Move to new file position.

Argument offset is a byte count.  Optional argument whence defaults to
0 (offset from start of file, offset should be >= 0); other values are 1
(move relative to current position, positive or negative), and 2 (move
relative to end of file, usually negative, although many platforms allow
seeking beyond the end of a file).  If the file is opened in text mode,
only offsets returned by tell() are legal.  Use of other offsets causes
undefined behavior.
Note that not all file objects are seekable.
```

help on `tell()`:

```
In [22]: print target.tell.__doc__
tell() -> current file position, an integer (may be a long integer).
```